# Use Javascript to submit a selected form within a division

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html page which is generated automatically with several forms on it. I am able to wrap each form in a div tag, but have no control over the content of the form.

I would like to have an index list at the top of the page which submits the appropriate form located further down the page.

I have checked into using JavaScript to submit a selected form using the onclick function and the id of the submit button. This would work if I was able to create an id for each submit button, but I can only id a division wrapping the form. Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

HTML: (what user sees)

- Click here for item 1
- Click here for item 2
- Click here for item 3

[buy item 1]

[buy item 2]

[buy item 3]

Comment: Why can't you give ID's to the forms?

Comment: can you post the HTML code for us to take a look at?

Comment: Every `input` element has a `form` property that gives you a direct reference to the form it's contained in. That might help if the submit button is an actual `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

Provided:

- you know the `id` of the `div`
- there is exactly one `form` in each `div`

You should be able to submit a `form` this way:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("id_of_the_div_containing_the_form");
var form = div.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.submit();
```

Or in a single line:

```js
document.getElementById("id").getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked great. I added the following function:

'code'function submitFormInDiv(div_id){
var div = document.getElementById(div_id);
var form = div.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
form.submit();
}